# request for member ‘begin’ in ‘ionDistance’, which is of non-class type ‘float*’

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written the code below and I am receiving the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
float sampledEnergies ( float ionDistance[], float ionEnergy[])
{

float   samTime[1000];
float   simPos[1000];
float   closeEnergy[1000];
float   close;
int     maxSamples = chamberLength / (driftVel * adcSampleRate);

for (int i = 0; i < maxSamples; i++)
{
    samTime[i] = i * adcSampleRate; 
    simPos[i] = chamberLength - (driftVel * samTime[i]);
    printf("%.2f\t%.2f\n",samTime[i],simPos[i]);

    close = lower_bound(ionDistance.begin(),ionDistance.end(), simPos[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < maxSamples; j++)
    {
        if (close = ionDistance[j])
        {
            closeEnergy[i] = ionEnergy[j];
        }
    }       
}

}
```

The above is the code and the error is as follows.

```
TBraggSimulation_v1.cpp: In function ‘float sampledEnergies(float*, float*)’:
TBraggSimulation_v1.cpp:37: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘ionDistance’, which is of non-class type ‘float*’
TBraggSimulation_v1.cpp:37: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘ionDistance’, which is of non-class type ‘float*’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ionDistance` is a pointer (to a first element of an array) and not a standard-library container. Your code tries to call `begin` and `end`, which are only defined for containers.

To obtain a range of iterators for a pointer, use:

```
lower_bound(ionDistance, ionDistance + n, simPos[i]);
```

Here `n` is the number of elements in your `ionDistance` array. I don't understand your code enough to suggest it's equal to `maxSamples`; if it's not, add a parameter to your function:

```
float sampledEnergies ( float ionDistance[], float ionEnergy[], size_t numIons)
{
    lower_bound(ionDistance,ionDistance + numIons, simPos[i]);
}
```