# request for member ‘begin’ in ‘c’, which is of non-class type ‘char [101]’ sort(c.begin(), c.end());

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stl

**CODE**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char c[101];
    cin>>c;
    sort(c.begin(), c.end());
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

**ERROR**
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:6:9: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘c’, which is of non-class type ‘char [101]’
  sort(c.begin(), c.end());
         ^~~~~
prog.cpp:6:20: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘c’, which is of non-class type ‘char [101]’
  sort(c.begin(), c.end());
                    ^~~

**INPUT USED**
3+2+1

**COMPILER USED**
language:
C++14 (gcc 8.3)

Comment: Do not include https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: `c` is an array. It has no members like `begin` and `end`.

Comment: You've shown an error, but you haven't asked a question. We can probably guess what that question is, but please ask it.

Comment: You will want to use `std::getline` to limit the input to the capacity of your array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [request for member ‘begin’ in ‘ionDistance’, which is of non-class type ‘float\*’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525824/request-for-member-begin-in-iondistance-which-is-of-non-class-type-float)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a iterable container, C++ provides a std::string class:

```
// do not use #include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>    //for cin and cout
#include <string>      //for string
#include <algorithm>  //for sort

int main() {
    std::string c; 
    std::cin >> c;
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks! I didn't know that. I've always thought, that there isn't any standard library and I only reffered to it as the "STL".

Comment: I think the only thing missing for this answer to be complete is mentioning that `char c[101];` could work if OP used `std::begin(c)` and `std::end(c)`. But `std::string` is still a better solution.

Comment: How to print it as 1+2+3?

Comment: @MohdArsalan Sounds like a different problem to me, try to read about scanners and parsers. What is the real problem you try to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not classes. They do not have member functions.

What you could do is the following.

As in this statement

```
cin>>c;
```

you are entering a string then you have to calculate the size of the string stored in the character array. To do this you have to include the header `<cstring>` where the standard function `strlen` is declared.

Then the call of `std::sort` can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char c[101];

    std::cin >> c;

    std::sort( c, c + std::strlen( c ) );

    std::cout << c << '\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```

However pay into account that if you will enter the string

```
3+2+1
```

then after sorting you will get

```
++123
```

Also the call

```
cin>>c;
```

is unsafe. Instead of it you could use member function `getline` of the class std::istream the following way

`std::cin.getline( c, sizeof( c ), '\n' );`

As an alternative instead of the character array you could use the standard class `std::string`.

Comment: How to print it as 1+2+3?

Comment: @MohdArsalan You could just reverse the string assuming that it is sorted in the descending order relative to the numbers. Otherwise you should use your own sort function.

Comment: and if it is 1+3+2?

Comment: @MohdArsalan You need to use your own sort function.